Unique decomposition of complex Borel measure
I need to prove that the following decomposition of complex Borel measure is unique.
$$\mu=\mu_d+\mu_{a c}+\mu_{sc}$$
Here
$\mu_d$=discerete measure, $\mu_{ac}$=absolutely continuous measure, $\mu_{sc}$=singular continuous measure. Both singularity and absolute continuity is with respect to standard borel measure $m$.
A proof in folland's real analysis is as follows.

Any complex measure $\mu$ can be written uniquely as $\mu=\mu_d+\mu_c$ where $\mu_d$ is discrete and $\mu_c$ is continuous.  A complex Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is called discrete if there is a countable set $\left\{x_j\right\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and complex numbers $c_j$ such that $\sum\left|c_j\right|<\infty$ and $\mu=\sum c_j \delta_{x_i}$, where $\delta_x$ is the point mass at $x$. On the other hand, $\mu$ is called continuous if $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Indeed, let $E=\{x: \mu(\{x\}) \neq 0\}$. For any countable subset $F$ of $E$ the series $\sum_{x \in F} \mu(\{x\})$ converges absolutely (to $\mu(F)$ ), so $\left\{x \in E:|\mu(\{x\})|>k^{-1}\right\}$ is finite for all $k$, and it follows that $E$ itself is countable. Hence $\mu_d(A)=\mu(A \cap E)$ is discrete and $\mu_c(A)=\mu(A \backslash E)$ is continuous.
Obviously, if $\mu$ is discrete, then $\mu \perp m$; and if $\mu \ll m$, then $\mu$ is continuous. Thus, by Theorem 3.22(Lebesgue Radon- Nikodyn theorem for complex measure), any (regular) complex Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written uniquely as
$$
\mu=\mu_d+\mu_{a c}+\mu_{s c}
$$
where $\mu_d$ is discrete, $\mu_{a c}$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $m$, and $\mu_{s c}$ is a "singular continuous" measure, that is, $\mu_{s c}$ is continuous but $\mu_{s c} \perp m$.

So first we uniquely decompose $\mu$ into $\mu_d+\mu_c$ and then uniquely decompose $\mu_c$ into $\mu_{ac}+\mu_{sc}$. The uniqueness of the second decomposition is through radon nikodyn theorem but how do I prove that the decomposition $\mu=\mu_d+\mu_c$ is unique. The text book proof gives us the decomposition but doesn't show us how it is unique
